# PHP Function to get MP3 duration

Tags: php, mp3

Is there any PHP function that will give me the MP3 duration. I looked at ID 3 function but i don't see any thing there for duration and apart from this,id3 is some kind of tag,which will not be there in all MP3 so using this will not make any sense.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should work for you, notice the getduration function: http://www.zedwood.com/article/127/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3

Comment: OK, works with PHP5 and not PHP4 so not sure you could get much more 'modern'

Comment: works fine, but sometimes it return Severity: Warning  --> fseek(): stream does not support seeking

Answer (score 28):

Install getid3, but if you only need duration, you can delete all but these modules:

- module.audio.mp3.php
- module.tag.id3v1.php
- module.tag.apetag.php
- module.tag.id3v2.php

Access the duration with code like this:

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($pathName);
$len= @$ThisFileInfo['playtime_string']; // playtime in minutes:seconds, formatted string
```

Get it at [Sourceforge](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: There's even a Drupal module for this https://www.drupal.org/project/getid3 and the documentation on http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ is great!

Comment: WordPress (4.7.5) includes version 1.9.9-20141121 of getID3 in core, #fyi.

Answer (score 15):

I have passed so many time, but without getID3 (http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) to get duration of audio file not possible.

1) First download library of getID3 using below link:

```
 https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/archive/master.zip
```

2) Try this below code:

```
    <?php
       include("getid3/getid3.php");
       $filename = 'bcd4ecc6bf521da9b9a2d8b9616d1505.wav';
       $getID3 = new getID3;
       $file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
       $playtime_seconds = $file['playtime_seconds'];
       echo gmdate("H:i:s", $playtime_seconds);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can get the duration of an mp3 or many other audio/video files by using ffmpeg.

1. Install ffmpeg in your server.
2. Make sure that php shell_exec is not restricted in your php.

   ```
       // Discriminate only the audio/video files you want
       if(preg_match('/[^?#]+\.(?:wma|mp3|wav|mp4)/', strtolower($file))){
           $filepath = /* your file path */;
           // execute ffmpeg form linux shell and grab duration from output
           $result = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$filepath.' 2>&1 | grep -o \'Duration: [0-9:.]*\'');
           $duration = str_replace('Duration: ', '', $result); // 00:05:03.25

           //get the duration in seconds
           $timeArr = preg_split('/:/', str_replace('s', '', $duration[0]));
           $t = $this->_times[$file] = (($timeArr[3])? $timeArr[3]*1 + $timeArr[2] * 60 + $timeArr[1] * 60 * 60 : $timeArr[2] + $timeArr[1] * 60)*1000;

       }
   ```

Comment: Seems a good thinking style for those unseekable remote URLs.

Comment: This is a good answer for me because it doesn't need to load whole file to get the duration. And can be used for remote file.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
class MP3File
{
protected $filename;
public function __construct($filename)
{
    $this->filename = $filename;
}

public static function formatTime($duration) //as hh:mm:ss
{
    //return sprintf("%d:%02d", $duration/60, $duration%60);
    $hours = floor($duration / 3600);
    $minutes = floor( ($duration - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
    $seconds = $duration - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);
    return sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}

//Read first mp3 frame only...  use for CBR constant bit rate MP3s
public function getDurationEstimate()
{
    return $this->getDuration($use_cbr_estimate=true);
}

//Read entire file, frame by frame... ie: Variable Bit Rate (VBR)
public function getDuration($use_cbr_estimate=false)
{
    $fd = fopen($this->filename, "rb");

    $duration=0;
    $block = fread($fd, 100);
    $offset = $this->skipID3v2Tag($block);
    fseek($fd, $offset, SEEK_SET);
    while (!feof($fd))
    {
        $block = fread($fd, 10);
        if (strlen($block)<10) { break; }
        //looking for 1111 1111 111 (frame synchronization bits)
        else if ($block[0]=="\xff" && (ord($block[1])&0xe0) )
        {
            $info = self::parseFrameHeader(substr($block, 0, 4));
            if (empty($info['Framesize'])) { return $duration; } //some corrupt mp3 files
            fseek($fd, $info['Framesize']-10, SEEK_CUR);
            $duration += ( $info['Samples'] / $info['Sampling Rate'] );
        }
        else if (substr($block, 0, 3)=='TAG')
        {
            fseek($fd, 128-10, SEEK_CUR);//skip over id3v1 tag size
        }
        else
        {
            fseek($fd, -9, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        if ($use_cbr_estimate && !empty($info))
        { 
            return $this->estimateDuration($info['Bitrate'],$offset); 
        }
    }
    return round($duration);
}

private function estimateDuration($bitrate,$offset)
{
    $kbps = ($bitrate*1000)/8;
    $datasize = filesize($this->filename) - $offset;
    return round($datasize / $kbps);
}

private function skipID3v2Tag(&$block)
{
    if (substr($block, 0,3)=="ID3")
    {
        $id3v2_major_version = ord($block[3]);
        $id3v2_minor_version = ord($block[4]);
        $id3v2_flags = ord($block[5]);
        $flag_unsynchronisation  = $id3v2_flags & 0x80 ? 1 : 0;
        $flag_extended_header    = $id3v2_flags & 0x40 ? 1 : 0;
        $flag_experimental_ind   = $id3v2_flags & 0x20 ? 1 : 0;
        $flag_footer_present     = $id3v2_flags & 0x10 ? 1 : 0;
        $z0 = ord($block[6]);
        $z1 = ord($block[7]);
        $z2 = ord($block[8]);
        $z3 = ord($block[9]);
        if ( (($z0&0x80)==0) && (($z1&0x80)==0) && (($z2&0x80)==0) && (($z3&0x80)==0) )
        {
            $header_size = 10;
            $tag_size = (($z0&0x7f) * 2097152) + (($z1&0x7f) * 16384) + (($z2&0x7f) * 128) + ($z3&0x7f);
            $footer_size = $flag_footer_present ? 10 : 0;
            return $header_size + $tag_size + $footer_size;//bytes to skip
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public static function parseFrameHeader($fourbytes)
{
    static $versions = array(
        0x0=>'2.5',0x1=>'x',0x2=>'2',0x3=>'1', // x=>'reserved'
    );
    static $layers = array(
        0x0=>'x',0x1=>'3',0x2=>'2',0x3=>'1', // x=>'reserved'
    );
    static $bitrates = array(
        'V1L1'=>array(0,32,64,96,128,160,192,224,256,288,320,352,384,416,448),
        'V1L2'=>array(0,32,48,56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,160,192,224,256,320,384),
        'V1L3'=>array(0,32,40,48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,160,192,224,256,320),
        'V2L1'=>array(0,32,48,56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160,176,192,224,256),
        'V2L2'=>array(0, 8,16,24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160),
        'V2L3'=>array(0, 8,16,24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160),
    );
    static $sample_rates = array(
        '1'   => array(44100,48000,32000),
        '2'   => array(22050,24000,16000),
        '2.5' => array(11025,12000, 8000),
    );
    static $samples = array(
        1 => array( 1 => 384, 2 =>1152, 3 =>1152, ), //MPEGv1,     Layers 1,2,3
        2 => array( 1 => 384, 2 =>1152, 3 => 576, ), //MPEGv2/2.5, Layers 1,2,3
    );
    //$b0=ord($fourbytes[0]);//will always be 0xff
    $b1=ord($fourbytes[1]);
    $b2=ord($fourbytes[2]);
    $b3=ord($fourbytes[3]);

    $version_bits = ($b1 & 0x18) >> 3;
    $version = $versions[$version_bits];
    $simple_version =  ($version=='2.5' ? 2 : $version);

    $layer_bits = ($b1 & 0x06) >> 1;
    $layer = $layers[$layer_bits];

    $protection_bit = ($b1 & 0x01);
    $bitrate_key = sprintf('V%dL%d', $simple_version , $layer);
    $bitrate_idx = ($b2 & 0xf0) >> 4;
    $bitrate = isset($bitrates[$bitrate_key][$bitrate_idx]) ? $bitrates[$bitrate_key][$bitrate_idx] : 0;

    $sample_rate_idx = ($b2 & 0x0c) >> 2;//0xc => b1100
    $sample_rate = isset($sample_rates[$version][$sample_rate_idx]) ? $sample_rates[$version][$sample_rate_idx] : 0;
    $padding_bit = ($b2 & 0x02) >> 1;
    $private_bit = ($b2 & 0x01);
    $channel_mode_bits = ($b3 & 0xc0) >> 6;
    $mode_extension_bits = ($b3 & 0x30) >> 4;
    $copyright_bit = ($b3 & 0x08) >> 3;
    $original_bit = ($b3 & 0x04) >> 2;
    $emphasis = ($b3 & 0x03);

    $info = array();
    $info['Version'] = $version;//MPEGVersion
    $info['Layer'] = $layer;
    //$info['Protection Bit'] = $protection_bit; //0=> protected by 2 byte CRC, 1=>not protected
    $info['Bitrate'] = $bitrate;
    $info['Sampling Rate'] = $sample_rate;
    $info['Framesize'] = self::framesize($layer, $bitrate, $sample_rate, $padding_bit);
    $info['Samples'] = $samples[$simple_version][$layer];
    return $info;
}

private static function framesize($layer, $bitrate,$sample_rate,$padding_bit)
{
    if ($layer==1)
        return intval(((12 * $bitrate*1000 /$sample_rate) + $padding_bit) * 4);
    else //layer 2, 3
        return intval(((144 * $bitrate*1000)/$sample_rate) + $padding_bit);
}
}
?>
<?php
$mp3file = new MP3File("Chal_Halke.mp3");//http://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510282
$duration1 = $mp3file->getDurationEstimate();//(faster) for CBR only
$duration2 = $mp3file->getDuration();//(slower) for VBR (or CBR)
echo "duration: $duration1 seconds"."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no native php function to do this.

Depending on your server environment, you may use a tool such as [MP3Info](http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/).

```
$length = shell_exec('mp3info -p "%S" sample.mp3');   // total time in seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

As earlier, I provided a solution for both **mp3** and **WAV** files, Now this solution is specifically for the only **WAV** file with more **precision** but with longer **evaluation** time than the earlier solution.

```
function calculateWavDuration( $file ) {

    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    if (fread($fp, 4) == "RIFF") {

        fseek($fp, 20);
        $raw_header = fread($fp, 16);
        $header = unpack('vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits', $raw_header);
        $pos = ftell($fp);

        while (fread($fp, 4) != "data" && !feof($fp)) {

            $pos++;
            fseek($fp, $pos);

        }

        $raw_header = fread($fp, 4);
        $data = unpack('Vdatasize', $raw_header);
        $sec = $data[datasize] / $header[bytespersec];
        $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
        $seconds = intval($sec % 60);

        return str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    }

}

$file = '1.wav'; //Enter File wav
calculateWavDuration($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have FFMpeg installed, getting the duration is quite simple with FFProbe

```
$filepath = 'example.mp3';
$ffprobe = \FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
$duration = $ffprobe->format($filepath)->get('duration');

echo gmdate('H:i:s', $duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

The MP3 length is not stored anywhere (in the "plain" MP3 format), since MP3 is designed to be "split" into frames and those frames will remain playable.

http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm

If you have no ID tag on which to rely, what you would need to do (there are tools and PHP classes that do this) is to read the whole MP3 file and sum the durations of each frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($pathName);

// playtime in minutes:seconds, formatted string
$len = @$ThisFileInfo['playtime_string']; 

//don't get playtime_string, but get playtime_seconds
$len = @$ThisFileInfo['playtime_seconds']*1000; //*1000 as calculate millisecond
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I developed a solution with my own calculations. This solution works best for **mp3** and **WAV** files formats. However minor precision variations are expected. The solution is in **PHP**. I take little bit clue from [WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)

```
function calculateFileSize($file){

    $ratio = 16000; //bytespersec

    if (!$file) {

        exit("Verify file name and it's path");

    }

    $file_size = filesize($file);

    if (!$file_size)
        exit("Verify file, something wrong with your file");

    $duration = ($file_size / $ratio);
    $minutes = floor($duration / 60);
    $seconds = $duration - ($minutes * 60);
    $seconds = round($seconds);
    echo "$minutes:$seconds minutes";

}

$file = 'apple-classic.mp3'; //Enter File Name mp3/wav
calculateFileSize($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg is mentioned elsewhere, but here's a fuller explanation and example implementation.

1. [Install ffmpeg for your system](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html). E.g., on Ubuntu:

`apt-get update && apt-get -y install ffmpeg`

2. Install [php-ffmpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) using Composer:

`composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg`

3. Example utility class

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use FFMpeg\FFProbe;

class Audio
{

   public static function duration(string $path): float
   {
        $probe = FFProbe::create();

        return $probe->format($path)->get('duration');
    }
}
```

Where `$path` is the absolute path or URL to your audio file. To use:

```
$duration = \App\Utils\Audio::duration($path);

echo $duration; // 24.476750
```

Of course, you can just use it directly where you need it. The point of the utility class example is to show how you use it. You'll want to try/catch calling it in a production setting. If you aren't using composer, see [@awavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15237692/2192679).