# MP3 file duration PHP

Tags: php

I worked with some mp3 files, and i needed to show duration of uploaded mp3 file, I used following: 
http://www.zedwood.com/article/127/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3 
as told in question: 
[PHP Function to get MP3 duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053125/php-function-to-get-mp3-duration).

But now I'm facing a problem, there are some files which are not returning any file information. 
the array just  contains following

```
Array (
    [Filesize] => 16756370,
    [Encoding] => Unknown
)
```

As the "Encoding" is Unknown its not returning any data.

Comment: Maybe it's not a proper MP3 file then? Check extension?

Comment: but its working fine, playing, im listening to it :)

Comment: I think that class only works with MP3 files with constant bitrate, not for VBR.

Answer (score 3):

I found a great PHP library, **getID3()**, that works for VBR files as well.

You can find it right here; it's free and is being developed actively (latest version is from from February 2013):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/files/getID3%28%29%201.x/1.9.5/