# Detecting and storing length of audio files in a table

Tags: php, mysql, audio

I need to get the length of the audio files people are uploading to my site and store it so that I can display the length when someone else is browsing the file. How do I do that? I am using MySQL database with php.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far ?

Comment: If you don't know where to start with such a thing its hard trying anything at all.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053125/php-function-to-get-mp3-duration)